# SELECT Columns WHERE one column Is Distinct?

Tags: t-sql, oledbcommand

Can anyone help me with the query ?

I've tried the following but it comes up with an error

```
SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM Table WHERE [Column1] NOT IN 
(SELECT [Column1] FROM Table GROUP BY [Column1] HAVING COUNT([Column]) > 1)
```

Invalid MEMO, OLE, or Hyperlink Object in subquery [Column1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Group By` with `Having` clause:

```
SELECT Column1, MIN(Column2)AS Column2, MIN(Column3)AS Column3
FROM dbo.Table
GROUP BY Column1
HAVING ( COUNT(Column1) = 1 )
```

Should work since there's only one row per "group".

Comment: Having the rest of the Columns in MIN() Function doesn't give me the exception. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your original query should work you just had column instead of column1.

```
 SELECT Column1, Column2, Column3 FROM TableName WHERE [Column1] NOT IN 
(SELECT [Column1] FROM TableName GROUP BY [Column1] HAVING COUNT(Column1) > 1)
```

see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d99a8/5/0

Answer (score 0):

As far as i get , you need all data where [Column1] is unique (appear just one time)

```
DECLARE @x TABLE (col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)

INSERT INTO @x
        ( [col1], [col2], [col3] )
VALUES  ( 1, 2, 3  )
        ,( 1, 4, 5 )
        ,( 2, 6, 7 )

SELECT * FROM @x

SELECT col1, col2 , col3 FROM @x
WHERE col1 NOT IN 
    ( SELECT [col1]  FROM @x GROUP BY [col1] HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1 )
```